# How to convert Array of Phalcon File Objects to simple array of array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, phalcon

I'm trying to convert array of files objects into an array of arrays but I always get empty results. I tried the below code but it gives me empty array

```
$json  = json_encode($this->request->getUploadedFiles());
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($array);exit;
```

**Result of above var_dump**:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }
```

**Array of Files Objects from POST Request**:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(Phalcon\Http\Request\File)#695 (8) { 
        ["_name":protected]=> string(52) "27657439_10157161194752222_6818734335050869731_n.jpg" 
        ["_tmp":protected]=> string(24) "D:\xampp\tmp\php145A.tmp" 
        ["_size":protected]=> int(31591) 
        ["_type":protected]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        ["_realType":protected]=> NULL 
        ["_error":protected]=> int(0) 
        ["_key":protected]=> string(9) "path_8" 
        ["_extension":protected]=> string(3) "jpg" 
    } 
    [1]=> object(Phalcon\Http\Request\File)#700 (8) { 
        ["_name":protected]=> string(8) "asif.PNG" 
        ["_tmp":protected]=> string(24) "D:\xampp\tmp\php145B.tmp" 
        ["_size":protected]=> int(425449) 
        ["_type":protected]=> string(9) "image/png" 
        ["_realType":protected]=> NULL 
        ["_error":protected]=> int(0) 
        ["_key":protected]=> string(9) "path_14" 
        ["_extension":protected]=> string(3) "PNG" 
    } 
}
```

**I need resultant array like below:**

```
array(2) { 
    ["path_8"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { 
            ["error"]=> int(0) 
            ["name"]=> string(14) "image-name.jpg" 
            ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
            ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpqImhgm" 
            ["size"]=> int(222301) 
        } 
        [1]=> array(5) { 
            ["error"]=> int(0) 
            ["name"]=> string(42) "WhatsApp Image 2018-02-20 at 18.48.13.jpeg" 
            ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
            ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php6HAWpJ" 
            ["size"]=> int(84153) 
        } 
    } 
    ["path_14"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { 
            ["error"]=> int(4) 
            ["name"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["type"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["size"]=> int(0)
         } 
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** var_dump($json) result

```
string(7) "[{},{}]"
```

and var_dump($this->request->getUploadedFiles());exit; result is

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(Phalcon\Http\Request\File)#673 (8) { 
        ["_name":protected]=> string(52) "27657439_10157161194752222_6818734335050869731_n.jpg" 
        ["_tmp":protected]=> string(24) "D:\xampp\tmp\php33AF.tmp" 
        ["_size":protected]=> int(31591) 
        ["_type":protected]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        ["_realType":protected]=> NULL 
        ["_error":protected]=> int(0) 
        ["_key":protected]=> string(9) "path_8" 
        ["_extension":protected]=> string(3) "jpg" 
    } 
    [1]=> object(Phalcon\Http\Request\File)#695 (8) { 
        ["_name":protected]=> string(8) "asif.PNG" 
        ["_tmp":protected]=> string(24) "D:\xampp\tmp\php33BF.tmp" 
        ["_size":protected]=> int(425449) 
        ["_type":protected]=> string(9) "image/png" 
        ["_realType":protected]=> NULL 
        ["_error":protected]=> int(0) 
        ["_key":protected]=> string(9) "path_14" 
        ["_extension":protected]=> string(3) "PNG" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: @Kaddath please check the updated question.

Comment: `path_14`, `path_8` result? input `path_12.0`, `path_12.1`? What is the logic to map this?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes question is completely unclear!

Comment: Your Examples MAKE SO SENSE! See @DrakulaPredator comment. Please make the result requirement MATCH the available inputs and then maybe we can help

Comment: @DrakulaPredator RiggsFolly yes sorry for the confusion, these are images keys. I updated it now.

Comment: Better but HOW do we generate **2** entries under the `path_8` array in the results both containing different data, non of which exists in the Input ??

Comment: Actually I have multiple upload buttons in my form. i.e Each question has uploader button where user can select multiple images. So I'm linking uploads to specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to parse like this:

```
$files = [];
foreach($this->request->getUploadedFiles() as $file){
   $item['name']     = $file->getName();
   $item['realType'] = $file->getRealType();
   $item['size']     = $file->getSize();
   ......................................
   $files[] = $item;
}
```

or you could overload the File class:
https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/Http/Request/File.zep
to implement ArrayAccess and you would also need to overload the Request class.

Comment: To convert this from a comment to an Answer I think it would be necessary to tell the OP how that would be done !

Comment: @Andrei i already have `toArray` option but it's not working on File object.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa by changing the structure a little bit I have got the desired results. Thanks

`$filesToSave[$item['key']] = $item;`